# Python Lambda function not published after saving (deploying) in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-lambda, publish

After editing `Lambda` function inline with `Python 3.8` and then pressing `"save"`...I get the message "`successfully deployed package`". Normally the updated function should be triggered after calling API again, but the updated code seems either not beeing deployed or whyever the new code is not called, I don´t know what happens there...it says successfully deployed package.

Does it take a while for AWS to "realy" make the new function available to public?

Thanks for reply.

**EDIT:**

found out that my browser had old version in cache I think...but this is a problem...why do I have to clear cache to test new version of API? It got published correctly but my browser used old version...how to prevent that?

Comment: Maybe your api gateway is set to specific version of the lambda function, not its latest one?

Comment: found out that my browser had old version in cache I think...but this is a problem...why do I have to clear cache to test new version of API? It got published correctly but my browser used old version...how to prevent that?

Comment: you may have enabled caching for your api in api gateway?

Comment: Glad to hear. Don't know the specific details of know browsers cache the content. Btw, you can answer your own question if you want.

Comment: @ArunK how disable this? and do you recommend to enable it? what are the benefits

Comment: here is it https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-caching.html. can you check if its enabled.

Comment: i haven't used api gateway caching. but the idea is if an api method for example `/list-ami-by-region/ap-southeast-2`, the output is always going to be always same until a new ami is introduced. you can cache it at the api gateway level. so that you can avoid querying the database.

Comment: I think Caching is the Cause, but in the new API-Gateway console I can not find anything pointing to caching, even under stages...I followed the documentation to enabling or disabling cache as @ArunK recommended. Any idea?